# Raspberry unbootable after unexpected shutdown

Tags: linux, shutdown, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a raspberry Pi, Model B.

I installed Raspbian on the SD card and I would like to use it as a SVN server.

I installed everything I need to work with it, and it works ok. The problem is that when it shuts down unexpectedly (i.e. there is a blackout, or DC power gets accidentally disconnected before shutting down the OS), it won't boot anymore. It hangs on a black screen and doesn't boot up.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What have you check so far? Have you ensure it isn't a monitor problem? Can you access the SD Card and all its files from a PC? Have you looked at questions like http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7009/will-not-boot-black-screen-only to see if it helps?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams The Rpi doesn't power up. Not only I see nothing on the monitor, I also am unable to access it via SSH (yes, I'm sure it works and it starts at boot, I configured the SVN server via SSH).

Comment: @MatthewWilliams There is no power button, there is just the power source... Anyway, when I turn it on, I see all the leds turned on, but it seems to never finish the boot. If I reinstall raspbian, it works fine, but I don't want to do it everytime there is a problem...

Comment: I ran into this issue many times, the filesystem on the SDcard gets corrupted when not properly unmounted. The way I worked around this is very simple, I installed the OS on a USB stick and the SDcard is only used during the boot sequence.

Comment: @stresscool yes, this is as you said a *workaround*, but what is the point of having a class 10 SD if I use a slow USB device for the OS? There must be a way to avoid it. I recently bought a Pine A64 and I don't have these issues, Raspberry is the only one that messes up the FS on unexpected shutdowns...